# Strapi API integration - Authenticated Super Admin Unable to access custom routes beyond 'ads' and 'ads/:id'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postman, strapi

Using: React, Node.js, Strapi, Postman.

I'm having trouble accessing **custom routes** that my authenticated user has access to view. As a super admin with all permissions in Strapi, I can send my Post request to /auth/local and I can log the JWT. I use the JWT in my get request to /ads or /ads/:id and I get the .json return data. If I try to access /ads/count or /brands, or /brands/:id, or any of the other routes, I get a "401 - unauthorized - you do not have the proper permissions". But I'm authenticated, and have access for everything in the Strapi backend.

I can't figure out the issue. If the issue is do to the header and fetch (as some posts here suggest), I'm unsure as to where to add that header and or how!

Any thoughts you have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could anything be in between you and your backend, like an ad blocker? Other than that, it might be helpful to provide the full request and response headers / body of a failing call to get more insight what's going on.

Comment: No ad blocker. Here are the request and response headers. Auth sections contains bearer token returned from earlier post request to /auth/local Request Headers Authorization: Bearer (omitted here) Content-Type: text/plain User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8 Accept: / Postman-Token: omitted here (unsure iif needed to hide) Host: localhost:1337 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Connection: keep-alive response header: { //your user identifier: 'myemail@email.com', password: 'password', }

Sidenote: I don't have anything added in params or headers section but didn't think I had to include that.

Comment: I've logged the users and checked the roles and things are logging correctly. Looks like the right object property is being logged.

Answer (score 0):

Policies were set up to authenticate incorrectly. Only needed to specify policies for lowest authenticated role required to access route. Had to include policy object in routes.json accordingly to match policies files.